# New extent size is not a perfect fit. error while changing PE in LVM

Tags: rhel, lvm, troubleshooting

I have /dev/sda11 with 1040Mib and create VG with vg3 named.

I have not mention -s for PE so it took 4 PE. I can delete it, but I want to change to PE 16.

While using vgchange -s command I am getting the error.

```
[root@r1 ~]# vgchange -s 16 vg3
  New extent size is not a perfect fit

<[root@r1 ~]# vgdisplay vg3
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg3
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               1.01 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              259
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0
  Free  PE / Size       259 / 1.01 GiB
  VG UUID               RjUvrB-GrDx-dmvR-10hQ-TcPd-8sWZ-rUg7fL>
```

I want to change the PE size from 4.00 MiB to 16.00 MiB.

Am I using the wrong command? Or, is there a different way to change the size of PEs?

Comment: I think you should specifiy the size suffix of `m` or `M` for `-s 16`.

Comment: There is no option -m or -M for vgchange.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/519172/how-to-change-volumegroup-pe-size#519174

Answer (score 1):

When changing the extent size, the existing VG size needs to be a multiple of the extent size. In your case, the existing VG size is 259 extents * 4 MiB = 1036 MiB. If you're planning to use 16 MiB extent size, the existing VG size is not a multiple of that (1036 MiB / 16 MiB does have a remainder).

From your vgdisplay, I see that you have no LVs allocated yet in the VG so the easiest in your case is to remove the existing VG:

```
vgremove vg3
```

and then recreate it with

```
vgcreate -s 16m vg3 /dev/path_to_the_pv_dev
```